# How is the angle of the front wheel found in Bicycle Kinematics Model for a Car

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, models

My question is, in a 4 wheel model, the front wheels have different angles. To simplify things bicycle model is used. In the bicycle model, there is an imaginary wheel in the middle of the front wheels as well as the rear wheels.

In this photo, how can I find the angle alpha in terms of beta and theta?
[image]

Comment: The angles are basically unreadable.

Comment: beta is the angle between the vertical and the wheel (on the right)
alpha is the same, just for the middle wheel
theta is for the wheel on the left.

I can rewrite them if you still have difficulty reading.